# Unable to download & install Laravel 5 with composer. Error: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm not able to download lavarvel installer using composer 1.2.0 (latest version)
The error received: Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
I googled and could not find the answer to fix this to problem.

If possible, someone please try to run this command `composer global require "laravel/installer"` to check if it works? I think the link to packaglist is no longer valid but I'm not sure.

[image]

```
C:\wamp\www\st>composer self-update -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file C:\Users\Louis\AppData\Local\Temp\composer-cacert-bcf331364fef73d53e4368ba519a6c3fcb21ea7836c3d8efad4ec32731e8152a.pem: valid
Executing command (C:\wamp\www\st): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (C:\wamp\www\st): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (C:\wamp\www\st): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Reading C:/Users/Louis/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Louis/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Running 1.2.0 (2016-07-19 01:28:52) with PHP 5.5.12 on Windows NT / 6.2
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions
You are already using composer version 1.2.0 (stable channel).
```

Comment: What happens if you try to copy and paste that URL in the browser?

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert 404 error

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Could you run `composer self-update -vvv` and let us know the results, please

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert I kept the default settings when install composer so I don't think I'm under a proxy. I ran the command I updated in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out this morning. The problem was Kaspersky Internet Security blocked the connection between my PC and packagist.org . I am surprised that it never happened to anyone but me.

*** Solution:
- Disable your antivirus for a momment and run the command installing Laravel.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

**Two ways of laravel install(normally i follow  step 1)**

step 1.

- download zip file from github https://github.com/laravel/laravel
- and unzip and put it on wamp/www(where you normally put your project)
- wamp>www>folderproject>**shift+right click**>open **command window
  here**>   write on composer ***composer install***

step 2.

go to wamp>www>hold shift and click right mouse ->open **command window here**->paste **composer create-project laravel/laravel** in command prompt
then go to laravel project then shift+ right click ,open **command window here**>write ***php artisan serve***

**Config Laravel**

•   after install laravel then goes to wamp>www>laravelproject
•   copy from here **.env.example**  ,and paste it here then **.env - Copy.example** will create,
•   then open sublime ,go to **.env - Copy.example** file right click and rename to **.env**  and enter
•   then goes to wamp>www>laravelproject ,shift+right click ,write ***php artisan key:generate*** in command promt

Answer (score 0):

Hey i guess you using **php 5.5** first upgrade your **php** version then install use

`composer global require "laravel/installer"`

if you don't want upgrade your php then 
use

`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

Comment: can you try create new project using composer `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: Uninstall evrything and upgrade php version then try to reinstall then if u get error give ur teamviewr

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the config.json-file for Composer has ""packagist": false" inside the file. Try opening the file and changing to : true"

Or run,

cd ~/.composer/vendor/bin

Then

composer global require "laravel/installer"

Answer (score 0):

you can easily first disable your antivirus , then check your version of php that you are using make sure that it is above PHP VERSION 5.5 then open your terminal or cmd then go to directory of composer then paste `composer global require "laravel/installer"